# Error checking balance: argument 'pubkey': 'str' object cannot be converted to 'Pubkey'

Tags: balance

I'm currently trying to use python's solana library to check my wallet's balance but for some reason I'm encountering this error. Importing PublicKey doesn't help out either, that gave me an error of "could not be resolved".

```
import asyncio
from solana.rpc.async_api import AsyncClient

address = "addy"

NETWORK = "mainnet-beta"

async def check_balance():
    async with AsyncClient(endpoint=f"https://api.{NETWORK}.solana.com") as client:
        previous_balance = 0

        while True:
            try:
                balance = await client.get_balance(address)
                balance_lamports = balance["result"]["value"]

                if balance_lamports != previous_balance:
                    print(f"Wallet balance changed: {balance_lamports / 1e9:.9f} SOL")
                    previous_balance = balance_lamports

            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error checking balance: {e}")

            await asyncio.sleep(5)  # Check every 5 seconds

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(check_balance())
```

Comment: Add the code to your question so that people can more easily spot what might have gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a `Pubkey` object into the `get_balance` method, instead of plain public key string.
Solution is to simply wrap your public key string with `Pubkey` class:

```
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey

address = Pubkey("addy") // This should be your valid 32 bytes public key
```